# Area of interest and Hough Line Detection for distorted lines accuracy

Tags: opencv, resize, hough-transform, distortion

I am trying to do segmentation of book spines stacked both horizontal and vertically. I have came across a problem when the picture is too big.
[image]

Only part of the image can be seen in the whole window, meaning it does not process the original image it is suppose to process:

[image]

The image it processed
[image]

The image it should process instead
[image]

I cannot even view the whole image which is suppose to be processed. Hence, I tried to minimise the window just for this picture using=>

cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size2i(image.cols/6, image.rows/6) ); // resize to 1/6 of the image

which lead to another problem, when the picture is small, it become too small that the straight lines cannot even be detected.

Hence, I tried =>
cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size2i(750, 400) );

this lead to another problem. While the image above is above to display the whole window, for smaller pictures, my houghline detection becomes more unstable.

[image]
[image]

Do anybody have an idea on how to solve this sizing problem? And also how to improve my Hough Line detection which is pretty unstable now to separate the books? I wish to draw a line in between the stack of books.

Hope to hear from you guys soon. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're resizing the image *before* you perform the Hough Transform, I think what you want to do it *afterwards*. This allows you to get enough resolution in your picture to get decent lines detected, and you can still view it on your monitor.

Secondly you want to improve detecting the separation between the books. My advice would be to perform a bit of **pre-processing** to the image. There are plenty of methods to do this. [Mean Shift Segmentation](http://www.ekran.org/ben/wp/2011/mean-shift-segmentation/) to separate the picture by colours is one for example.

**Filtering the results** of the transform is another approach. Only keeping lines passing through dark areas - since it is more likely to be dark between the books - is one such way. There are plenty more methods.

Also don't forget to [tweak the parameters of the Hough Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html#explanation) to see what works best with your test set. It may reveal some interesting results!

**Good luck!**

Comment: Hi, in regard to the resizing, tried that method too, but the line drawing will go all haywire as well. for drawing the detected straight lines, I use  vector<Vec2f> lines. I do not think there is exactly a method to resize vector? For temporary purpose, I worked my way around it by resizing the picture using paint before opening it with my program. Of course, I still want to resolve that problem though, imagine somebody playing with my program and face that problem. You have any other idea what could have cause this? I never encounter such problem before.

Comment: In regard to the book segmentation, I have thought of the filtering the results where i find the dark areas between the books too! I will try your advice on pre-processing to the image. Greatly appreciate your suggestions and help (:

Comment: No problem! To resize a vector in the same way as your image, just multiply your x value by: desired_image_width/current_image_width and your y value by: desired_image_height/current_image_height

Answer (score 1):

IMO first you have to improve edge detected output.It consists of very less edges.You can use **cvCanny** or **cvSobel** for the same.Also use **Probabilistic Hough lines**, that will give better results.You can tweak into the parameters of **cvHoughLines** such as threshold, minLinLength, maxLineGap as in the fig the lines are coming too close.
Please check the details here:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: probabilistic Hough Lines vs Hough Lines for this case actually plays the same role. I have tried tweaking both, and normal Hough actually seems to be better. Maybe the way I played around the parameters of the HoughLineP was slightly wrong. Yup. I share the same sentiment as you of improving the edges. I am reading up on Sobel now. i hope it will be effective. Thanks! (: